# ActivityResultContract opens gallery twice

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I'm currently switching the ActivityResults on an Android app (java) with ActivityResultContract (because of deprecation) as suggested by Google https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result. [Example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7yMu.png)

When I implement the same example code to get an image from gallery, shown in the link above, the activityResult opens not only the default image chooser, but also asks me to choose an app to select the image:
[App opening image chooser and asking to choose an app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWEMX.jpg)

Is there a way to avoid asking for an app to choose an image?

Comment: share your code, that way we maybe able to help !

Comment: The images are the other two links besides the one to developer.android, the call to activityResultContract is the same as the one in the example code.

Comment: Welcome @navi95! In order for the community to better assist you please follow the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ActivityResultLauncher instead. It will open the system gallery to pick an image from it.

Just follow these steps :-

1. First create the ActivityResultLauncher like this :

   ```
   ActivityResultLauncher<String> mGetContent = 
            registerForActivityResult(new GetContent(), new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
      // Handle the returned Uri
    }
   });
   ```
2. Then, launch system image picker on button click or whenever you want.

   ```
   mGetContent.launch("image/*");
   ```